# Найти члены предложения

Tags: члены-предложения

Найти члены предложения в предложении "Их мечта серьёзно заниматься спортом наконец стала реальностью"

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что дом/зад.

Answer (score 2):

**Их мечта серьёзно заниматься спортом наконец стала реальностью.**

Мечта стала реальностью: подлежащее + сказуемое (составное именное).

Мечта (чья?) их  ―  определение, мечта (какая?) заниматься спортом ―  определение.

Заниматься (как?) серьёзно ― обстоятельство образа действия,  стала (когда?) наконец ― обстоятельство времени.

Comment: А он думать не разучится?

Comment: Извините,  только в виде исключения. Дело в том, что оборот на основе инфинитива затрудняет понимание структуры предложения.